# PySpark ModuleNotFoundError on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyspark

I'm trying to run a Pyspark Streaming program on GCP Dataproc. I pip install mmh3 in ssh already, running pyspark then type import mmh3 caused no problem. But when I started running sc.start() and send info over from another ssh terminal, it starts saying the module not found. Any idea why this happened or how to fix it? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By installing the package via SSH, you're just install it on the "driver" node. You'll need to install the package for the **whole cluster** (i.e. all worker nodes) as well. Try following the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/python-configuration)